# MySQL Trigger create multiple records based on fields changed in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL Trigger that creates a "Task Event Log" record in another DB table when a Task record is modified.

The Event record that the Trigger creates can only be as specific as "Task edited" and now I need something more advanced.

I need to create separate Event log records for each Task field that is modified.

If a Task title, description, and due date are all changed, I need to make 3 event records, 1 for each field modified.  "Task Due Date modified"

Is there a way to create separate Event table records for each task field that is "modified" using Triggers?

The main reason for using Triggers is that I have a mass update Task page that allows to mass update all task records and all there field values.  It also allows drag and drop to change there sort order and when just the sot order changes on records, it will not make that taks modified date change unless real task fields are changed as well.

```
BEGIN
IF NOT (NEW.date_modified <=> OLD.date_modified)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO apoll_web_projects_events (event_type, project_id, task_id, created_by_user_id, description, date_created) VALUES ('7', NEW.project_id, NEW.task_id, NEW.modified_user_id, NEW.name, UTC_TIMESTAMP());
    END IF;
END
```

[image]

Here is my MySQL Query that mass updates Task records making sure to only update the modified date field when changed field criteria are met.

Then the Trigger fires on just the records that did meet the criteria and updated the date_modified field.

```
        INSERT INTO
            $this->tasksDbTableName(task_id, project_id, created_by_user_id, modified_user_id, name, description, status, priority, type, date_entered, date_modified, date_started, date_completed, date_due, milestone_id, assigned_user_id, sort_order, heading)
        VALUES
            ($db->quote($taskId), '$projectId', '$created_by_user_id', '$modified_user_id', '$name', '$description', '$status', '$priority', '$type', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), '$date_started', '$date_completed', '$date_due', '$milestone_id', '$assigned_user_id', '$sort_order', '$heading')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            date_modified = (CASE
                WHEN name <> values(name)
                OR description <> values(description)
                OR status <> values(status)
                OR type <> values(type)
                OR priority <> values(priority)
                  THEN UTC_TIMESTAMP()
                  ELSE date_modified
            END),
            modified_user_id='$modified_user_id',
            name='$name',
            description='$description',
            status='$status',
            priority='$priority',
            type='$type',
            date_started='$date_started',
            date_completed='$date_completed',
            date_due='$date_due',
            milestone_id='$milestone_id',
            assigned_user_id='$assigned_user_id',
            sort_order='$sort_order',
            heading='$heading'
```

In the SQL above, when criteria is met that make it go ahead and update a Task record, is there a way to have it also fire off some sort of event to create a Event record for each field that is is updating?

Comment: Why you can't just add another INSERTs in the same TRIGGER?

Comment: @Marki555 possibly you can, I am not sure?  What I mean is that in the trigger I would need to know which of about 6 task record fields had changed and only create a new record for the fields that had changed.  So if `due date` on 1 record changed it would create an event record for the due date change but not for another task that might instead need a title change event record created.

Comment: AFAIK the trigger gets executed for every changed row... and inside it you can check which fields got actually changed and do an INSERT for all of them which did change

Comment: @Marki555 well that sounds like just what I need but I haven't found a way to do that just yet or know for sure that it is possible even